# Multiple Selection Criteria

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table that contains:

- EmployeeID
- JobTitle
- StartDate
- EndDate

The minimum number of records for each EmployeeID is 1, for this scenario, there isn't really a max - some people have 10, 20, 30 etc.

I need to select from this table only these records:

1. If the colleague has only 1 record ALWAYS select it
2. If the colleague has multiple records - select them all, EXCEPT where the records StartDate is equal to the EndDate - ignore those records
3. If a colleague has multiple records, and the StartDate / EndDate are the same in every single one, then only bring through the record with the latest EndDate.

Probably easier to see with some examples - imagine this set of data - the last column (SELECT??) shows what I would want to do with that record.

```
+------------+----------+------------+------------+----------+
| EmployeeID | JobTitle | StartDate  |  EndDate   | SELECT?? |
+------------+----------+------------+------------+----------+
|        123 | A        | 01/01/2018 | 01/01/2018 | Y        |
|        456 | A        | 01/01/2018 | 01/01/2018 | N        |
|        456 | B        | 20/01/2018 | 20/02/2018 | Y        |
|        456 | C        | 21/02/2018 | 20/04/2018 | Y        |
|        789 | A        | 15/03/2018 | 15/03/2018 | N        |
|        789 | B        | 15/04/2018 | 15/04/2018 | N        |
|        789 | C        | 15/05/2018 | 15/05/2018 | Y        |
+------------+----------+------------+------------+----------+
```

I'm trying to do this as simply as possible, and I'm struggling without using a complicated set of CTE's

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because in order for us to help you with your issue, you need to provide some indication of what you have tried to solve the issue, and where you're struggling. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 2):

I think this can be achieved through UNION ALL -

```
SELECT EmployeeID, JobTitle, StartDate, EndDate
FROM Table
GROUP BY EmployeeID, JobTitle
HAVING COUNT(JobTitle) = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT EmployeeID, JobTitle, StartDate, EndDate
FROM Table
WHERE StartDate <> EndDate
GROUP BY EmployeeID, JobTitle
HAVING COUNT(JobTitle) > 1
UNION ALL
SELECT EmployeeID, JobTitle, MAX(StartDate), MAX(EndDate)
FROM Table
WHERE StartDate = EndDate
GROUP BY EmployeeID
HAVING COUNT(JobTitle) > 1
```

Though I have not tried it yet I think something like this should work.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when startdate <> enddate then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by employeeId) as cnt_notequal,
             row_number() over (partition by employeeId order by enddate desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where (cnt_notequal > 0 and startdate <> enddate) or
      (cnt_notequal = 0 and seqnum = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will be suitable:

```
select EmployeeID,
       JobTitle,
       StartDate,
       EndDate
from (select *,test = (case when StartDate = EndDate then
                      lead(EndDate) over (partition by EmployeeID order by EndDate)
                 else null end)
     from @table as t
     ) as t
where test is null
```

[**test is here**](http://rextester.com/MFQBO8912)